# Trouble about python terminal in linux mint cinnamon 19

Tags: python, linux, input, terminal

I am  using  atom for ide. My python code works fine except when I use input() in my code: nothing happen, just a blank terminal.

The same thing with other ide or directly in terminal with the command python.

Comment: `input()` will wait for you to type something.  if you have doubt weather your program is running, use `input("Enter values")`, which will print "Enter values" and wait for your input.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the solution is so simple.